# renaming column in dataframe for Pandas using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe made by Pandas that I want to remove the empty space at the end of each column name. I tried something like:

```
raw_data.columns.values = re.sub(' $','',raw_data.columns.values)
```

But this is not working, anything I did wrong here?

Comment: If the empty space is at the *end* of the column names, shouldn't it be `re.sub(' $', '')`?

Comment: sorry for the wrong regex there, I tried the corrected one but python responded `type error`

Answer (score 52):

I should have used [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
raw_data = raw_data.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(' $','',x))
```

Or to change in-place:

```
raw_data.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(' $','',x), inplace=True)
```

Comment: This will only remove 1 space.Use this if you want to remove all.`raw_data.columns.values = re.sub(r'[ ]*$','',raw_data.columns.values)`

Comment: would this work if the resulting column names were non-unique?

Comment: I tried my hand at looping through columns [for col in df.columns], using regex to identify what I needed to remove, and then re-name the columns one-by-one, which worked just fine, but was very slow. Your solution is much more performant! (for context: I was stripping a column-counter, i.e. (1), (2), ... (300), so that's why I needed regex)

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend using [pandas.Series.str.strip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html)

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer from @Christian is probably right for this specific question, but to the more general question about replacing names in the columns, I would suggest to create a dictionary comprehension and pass it to the rename function:

```
df.rename(columns={element: re.sub(r'$ (.+)',r'\1', element, flags = re.MULTILINE) for element in df.columns.tolist()})
```

In my case, I wanted to add something to the beginning of each column, so:

```
df.rename(columns={element: re.sub(r'(.+)',r'x_\1', element) for element in df.columns.tolist()})
```

You can use the inplace=True parameter to actually make the change in the dataframe.